# RewriteEngine: URL changes automatically in browser adress bar to old-style

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I put my RewriteEngine in my .htaccess to ON.

mydomain.de = localhost

When I write my adress: http://mydomain.de/~user/website/de, the adress reaches the right target, but change autmatically to http://mydomain.de/~user/website/index.php?lang=de
How can I prevent this?

The only thing I made in my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteRule ^de|en/?$ http://mydomain.de/~user/website/index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Sorry, I'm really new in the RewriteEngine Theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `http://` from target URI:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~user/webseite/

RewriteRule ^(de|en)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

If target URI contains `http://` then it is always an external redirect instead of an internal rewrite.

Comment: OK, the thing is, at first i try to make it local...so the real URL i use at first: http://127.0.0.1/~user/website/index.php?lang=de! I changed it in the question.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and index.php? Are they both in `~user/website`?

Comment: Yes! All in the same folder!

Comment: When i make the changes as you told me without http there is an error: The requested URL /Users/user/Sites/webseite/127.0.0.1/~user/webseite/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Did you try: `RewriteRule ^(de|en)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` ?

Comment: But you commented above that `index.php` is available in `~user/webseite/`

Comment: Yes i tried: error: The requested URL /Users/user/Sites/webseite/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: What id DOCUMENT_ROOT set to? Is it `/Users/user/Sites/webseite/127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: sorry, how can I do that? do I have to set it in the .htaccess?

Comment: No not in .htaccess that is set in Apache server config.

Comment: YES!! It works!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! So Rewrite Base is telling where the rewrite should start?

Comment: yes that's why I was asking about DOCUMENT_ROOT but got the answer after looking at your original URL again :P